# How to write a grep that pick up specific word in the third line?

Tags: git, grep, changelog

For example if I have a doc with these 3 lines. I know `^feat` is matching the first `feat` and how can I match the third line `reg`? I tried `^reg` does not seems work.

```
feat(ad): make new ad
some note here
reg(ad): need a walk through
```

It meant to be used within a `.changelogrc` file for https://github.com/rafinskipg/git-changelog

Comment: what exact output do you want?

Comment: @fedorqui so basically its a grep will be used inside git-changelog to grab the string `reg` and create a headline of `Regression` but that I think got handled by git-changelog lib, all I need is to write the correct grep, I think!

Comment: Yes, I understand you want the correct `grep`. But for that we need to know what output you want to extract for this given input. `grep "^reg"` seems to be ok.

Comment: @fedorqui hum... sounds like I have to dig into the lib, since I wrote `^reg`, and it did not work. so I thought maybe jus that my grep is not right

Comment: What output do you get when you run the command?

Comment: it seems just got eaten up, all other tags got processed, but not `reg` one. Also, I applied the answer below, basically all my tag related content result got eaten up.....

Comment: @EdMorton sorry lib means library which I referred to in the question. it does deal with grep though. it was indicated inside the `.changelogrc` file. If you feel my question not clear, feel free ask for clarification.

Comment: @EdMorton ok, sure, let me clarify. if the question is partially related to `grep` then I suppose grep should be in the tag, is like asking question about using react inside angular. Should someone just tag angular just because angular is the framework? or just tag react? tag both make sense, right? Feel free to prove your statement with an official statement on such way of tagging is not accurate. I am open. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following regex:

```
^[^\r\n]*?\r\?\n[^\r\n]*?\r\?\nreg
```

This regex will "eat" two lines from the beginning, and then check if `reg` appears at the start of the third line.  Note that I used the quantity `\n|\r\n` to represent a newline, to cover both Windows or Linux (you never mentioned your OS).

If you want to match *any* line which starts with `reg` then you can try:

```
^(?:[^\r\n]*?\r\?\n)*reg
```

Comment: Instead of `(?:\n|\r\n)` you can simply use `\r?\n` or for basic regex in grep `\r\?\n`. But I don't think it is always in the third line, though OP could be interpreted like that.

Comment: @Vampire I can give a more generic answer, one minute.

Comment: Btw. did you try your solution? It doesn't seem to work for me. Besides that `^reg` should work perfectly fine with `--grep`.

Comment: I don't think your solution can work, simply because grep is line-based and you cannot do multi-line matches without prior pre-processing that makes one long line out of the input using `sed` or similar. And in the case of OP this is not possible has it is the `--grep` `git-log` option that is used and not a standard bash pipeline with grep executable in it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the sources of that tool, you should enable debug logging to see the git command that is issued which is logged with `this.log('debug', 'Executing : ', git_log_command);`. From a quick look at the sources I'd say you get something like `git log --grep="^feat|^reg"` which is not correct but should instead be `git log --grep="^feat\|^reg"`. But anyway, if you have the log line, you can try to execute the command standalone to see whether it works for you and can play with it to find out why not if not.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I can check it a bit later on the debug log! also, what that extra `\` does for it? I quickly glanced the grep doc, but seems still not really see what `\` does stand alone, I only saw doc says it combine with `\w` or `\n` things like that.

Comment: It is not stand-alone. It changes the `|` from a literal pipe character to a regex meta-character that stands for alteration in basic regex that are by default used by grep if you do don't tell it to use extended or posix regex syntax: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended